# When do we use more with adjective?

Tags: grammar, comparative

Is it when the comparative form of an adjective is not available?

For example;

•Conjuring 2 is more horrible than The Nun

•Conjuring 2 is creepier than The Nun

Comment: **Horror** is a noun. The adjective is **horrible**. Thus **more horrible** (or **creepier/more creepy** (Not sure that creepy has an established comparative form).

Comment: google lists creepier as being comparative form of creepy

Comment: I see that **creepier** is widely approved but **more creepy** gets an occasional look in. http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/creepy

Answer (score 1):

The comparative of a two-syllable adjective ending in *-y* is formed by adding *-ier*.

> easy - easier
>
> creepy - creepier

We can say

> easy - more easy
>
> creepy - more creepy

but it's less usual.

<sub>Source: Grammarway 4 by Jenny Dooley and Virginia Evans</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere that two-syllable adjectives that end in -y can have two forms for comparison, for example easy-easier/more easy; happy-happier/more happy. But I don't think it is a rule in English, the language where a most economical form is preferred. So, although  it's not grammatically wrong to say "more easy/happy/ugly (etc.)", it is just not normal in English

Also, there's quite a lot of adjectives which cannot vary in intensity or grade and have a quality that can't be compared. They are called absolute adjectives, and *horrible* from your example is one of them ([here's a list](http://www.englishokay.com/absolute-adjectives-list.shtml) of some of those).